# How correctly type generic function which should receive Union type as a parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have different types and their unions.

Code:

```
type A = {
    name: string
  }

  type B = {
    work: boolean
  }

  type AB = A[] | B[]

  const func = (): AB => {
    return [{ name: 'ww' }]
  }

  const data = func()
```

I want to pass parameter of type union to a generic function.

```
export const randomGenericFunction = <O, T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  param1: O,
  param2: T[]
) => {
...
const d = param2.map(p => p)
...
}
```

But when I am passing it like this

```
randomGenericFunction('param1', data)
```

I am getting an error

```
Argument of type 'AB' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A[]'.
  Type 'B[]' is not assignable to type 'A[]'.
    Property 'name' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'A'.
```

And if I hover over `randomGenericFunction` call I can see that it is casting `T` as `A[]` and not `AB`

I am guessing it is caused by the fact that `T` is not actually a union type, so it "sees" only the first type in the union?

My question is, how can I type `T` param in the generic function as a union in that case?

Comment: Please check whether [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK9jZN) works for you

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine yes, it works! So I just typed the generic function wrong I guess, and it has nothing to do with union? Welp >_< Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use different constraint for your generics:

```js
type A = {
  name: string
}

type B = {
  work: boolean
}

type AB = A[] | B[]

const func = (): AB => {
  return [{ name: 'ww' }]
}

const data = func()

export const randomGenericFunction = <O, T extends Record<string, unknown>[]>(
  param1: O,
  param2: T
) => {

  const d = param2.map(p => p)

}
randomGenericFunction('param1', data) // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ7Jkw)

I have used `T extends Record<string, unknown>[]` instead of `T extends Record<string, unknown>`